# how i can get 0 for no records using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to mySql.  I have to calculate the count of clicks from table as per the week days.

Here period depends upon database. But what happens is if last week does not have records, it was not in the list. But I need it as 0. So for that how I can do?

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
                AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK THEN '22-28 days ago'

    WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK
                AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK THEN '15-21 days ago'

    WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
        AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN '8-14 days ago'

    WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
                THEN 'up to 7 days ago'
           END WeekPeriod, IFNULL(count(CLICKS),0) TotalClicks

FROM TABLE

WHERE PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK

GROUP BY CASE 
    WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
                    AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK THEN '22-28 days ago'

    WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK
                AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK THEN '15-21 days ago'

    WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
                AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN '08-14 days ago'

    WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
                THEN '01 to 7 days ago'

END
 ORDER BY WeekPeriod";
```

answer should be like this

```
1-7 0 
8-15 14 
16-21 34 
21-28 45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT uq.timespan, COALESCE(tsq.TotalClicks, 0) as Clicks FROM (
SELECT '22-28 days ago' as timespan
union SELECT '15-21 days ago'
union SELECT '8-14 days ago'
union SELECT 'up to 7 days ago'
)uq LEFT JOIN (
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
                AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK THEN '22-28 days ago'
    WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK
                AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK THEN '15-21 days ago'
    WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
        AND PERIOD < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN '8-14 days ago'
    WHEN PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN 'up to 7 days ago'
           END WeekPeriod, 
           count(CLICKS) TotalClicks
FROM TABLE
WHERE PERIOD >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
GROUP BY WeekPeriod
/*ORDER BY WeekPeriod -- unnecessary, GROUP BY implicits ORDER BY*/
)tsq ON uq.timespan = tsq.WeekPeriod
```

Comment: how i can do this for last 4 months instead of last 4 weeks? tried but not getting correct results. –

Comment: @BhavaniMalladi Replace `INTERVAL 4 WEEK` with `INTERVAL 4 MONTH`

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes i tried with replacing week by month. i need output as by month. like nov, oct, sep, aug

Comment: Ask in another question, please. I'd recommend you don't do it on database layer, but in a layer atop, with PHP or whatever you're using.

Comment: yes posted question please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250635/how-i-can-get-these-with-mysql

Comment: actually it have many loops. to eliminate atleast months i have to go like this. Thanks for your concern.