# how i can get these with mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to mysql.

I have on survey with clicks, period(date). Now i have to find out number of clicks per month, like:

```
MON  CLICKS
nov  0 
oct  34 
sep  67 
aug  89
```

I have used code like this:

```
select MONTHNAME(period) mon,  IFNULL(count(id),0) as Clicks
from survey
where period > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
group by EXTRACT(MONTH FROM period)
```

It is not working for with no records.

Here one thing I suppose there is no record in that month it should show 0: if there is no record in `nov` the number of clicks should be `0`.

```
my table structure was like this 
CREATE TABLE `survey` (
  `id` int(2) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   `period` datetime default NULL)
```

for last four weeks i have used

```
 SELECT uq.timespan, COALESCE(tsq.TotalClicks, 0) as Clicks FROM (
SELECT '22-28 days' as timespan
union SELECT '15-21 days'
union SELECT '8-14 days'
union SELECT 'up to 7 days'

)uq LEFT JOIN (
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
                AND submitdate < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK THEN '22-28 days'
    WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK
           AND submitdate < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK THEN '15-21 days'
WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
    AND submitdate < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN '8-14 days'
WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN 'up to 7 days'
       END Weeksubmitdate, 
           count(id) TotalClicks
FROM  survey 
WHERE submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
GROUP BY Weeksubmitdate
)tsq ON uq.timespan = tsq.Weeksubmitdate
```

Any help?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand, what you're about to do. And why are you selecting `MONTHNAME(period)` but grouping by `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM submitdate)`? Start by using the same there. Also you have to be careful with those backticks. I guess you had a syntax error? Those backticks let mysql treat it as a column name.

Comment: @Bhavani Malladi- Please provide your table structure

Comment: @tombom thanks for your reply. Actually i have to show number of clicks, average per each survey on graph.

Comment: @BhavaniMalladi Create table survey.... please give me full query to create table.. If possible give some sample data. And provide what result you want(Expecting result)

Comment: @BhavaniMalladi - i cant run query in your last comment. Please provide correct query to create table.

Comment: @FathahRehmanP here take clicks as id

Comment: select MONTHNAME(period) mon,  IFNULL(count(id),0) as Clicks from survey where `period> DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) group by EXTRACT(MONTH FROM period)` it is the correct query

Comment: @BhavaniMalladi, please edit your question (click 'edit' at the bottom of your question) and add the Survey CREATE code to it. That's very useful information for the people wanting to answer your question!

Comment: @Josien thanks. table structure was added.

Comment: @BhavaniMalladi-your survey table contain date of click right?

Comment: @BhavaniMalladi- can i do a trick? Its not the proper way, but it'll work

Comment: @BhavaniMalladi - Add a dummy date for each month in your survey table. Then use following query 
select MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month(period), '%m'))as 'month',count(*)-1 as clicks
 from survey group by month(period)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19163/discussion-between-fathah-rehman-p-and-bhavani-malladi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do Pivot table to achieve this. Assuming your click information is stored into a table named SURVEY and assuming only the date/time of the click is stored into one column of the SURVEY table (which is all what you need) then here is one way to do it:

```
select   year(period),
         sum(case when month(period)=1 then 1 else 0 end) jan,
         sum(case when month(period)=2 then 1 else 0 end) feb,
         sum(case when month(period)=3 then 1 else 0 end) mar,
         sum(case when month(period)=4 then 1 else 0 end) apr,
         sum(case when month(period)=5 then 1 else 0 end) may,
         sum(case when month(period)=6 then 1 else 0 end) jun,
         sum(case when month(period)=7 then 1 else 0 end) jul,
         sum(case when month(period)=8 then 1 else 0 end) aug,
         sum(case when month(period)=9 then 1 else 0 end) sep,
         sum(case when month(period)=10 then 1 else 0 end) oct,
         sum(case when month(period)=11 then 1 else 0 end) nov,
         sum(case when month(period)=11 then 1 else 0 end) dec
from     survey
group by year(period)
```

The output is something like:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Year  | JAN | FEB | MAR | APR | MAY | JUN | JUL | AUG | SEP | OCT | NOV | DEC |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2012  |  5  |  20 |  13 | 0   |  0  |  65 |  15 |  0  |  0  |  21 |  0  |  0  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I even set up the same Fiddle SQL for you
[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a79a/1/0)

An alternative way (Column based for the last 4 months even with **ZERO** count):
[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aea68/3)

```
SELECT mon,
       sum(clicks) clicks
FROM   ( SELECT month(period) mnth,
                date_format(period,'%b') mon,
                count(1) clicks
         FROM   survey
         WHERE  month(period) BETWEEN month(curdate()) - 4 AND month(curdate())
         GROUP BY 1, 2
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 1 mnth, 'Jan' mon, 0 clicks
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2 mnth, 'Feb' mon, 0 clicks
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3 mnth, 'Mar' mon, 0 clicks
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4 mnth, 'Apr' mon, 0 clicks
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 5 mnth, 'May' mon, 0 clicks
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6 mnth, 'Jun' mon, 0 clicks
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 7 mnth, 'Jul' mon, 0 clicks
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 8 mnth, 'Aug' mon, 0 clicks
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 9 mnth, 'Sep' mon, 0 clicks
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 10 mnth, 'Oct' mon, 0 clicks
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 11 mnth, 'Nov' mon, 0 clicks
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 12 mnth, 'Dec' mon, 0 clicks) a
WHERE  mnth BETWEEN month(curdate()) - 4 AND month(curdate())
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY mnth
```

Comment: Not exactly what was asked for, is it?

Comment: thanks for your reply. how to select last 4 months. suppose now it is aug i need aug, july,june,may

Comment: thanks for your reply. it is not working when there is no record in the month.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot about that. I will fix it and let you know

Comment: answer is perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to a table that contains all month names. Here's one way to do it:

```
select
    mon,
    ifnull(count(id), 0) as Clicks
from (select 'nov' as mon union select 'oct' union select 'sep' union select 'aug') m
left join survey on MONTHNAME(period) = mon
where submitdate > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH) 
group by 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. not selected months like nov, oct, sep, aug. every time last 4 months.

Answer (score 0):

```
select MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month(period), '%m'))as 'month',count(*) as clicks
 from survey group by month(period)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. its not working with month which have no records